# How to make login in asp.net MVC4?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am making Login in my website but its not working.
Registration is working successfully.
Here is my action method

```
[HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(Registration U)
        {
            Response.Write(U.Username); // it print the name but not go inside the condition
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {                        // not come here why?
                Response.Write("inin");
                ModelState.Clear();
                using (Database1Entities db = new Database1Entities())
                {
                    var user = db.Registrations.Where(a => a.Username.Equals(U.Username) && a.Password.Equals(U.Password)).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (user != null)
                    {
                        Session["LoggedUserID"] = U.Id.ToString();
                        Session["LoggedUsername"] = U.Username.ToString();
                        return RedirectToAction("Update");
                    }
                }
            }
            return View();
        }
```

it recived value from view that i checked by using response.write(U.username)
but why it not come in the condition if(modelstate.isvalid)?

here is my view

```
@model Final_Year_Project.Models.RegistrationMetaData

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>

        @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
            @Html.LabelFor(a=>a.Username)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(a=>a.Username)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a=>a.Username)
            <br>
             @Html.LabelFor(a=>a.Password)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(a=>a.Password)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a=>a.Password)

            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="Login">
        }



 @section Scripts{
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")}


    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

Another problem is its not show dots in password field

I set datatype.password in metadata . it working right in register view.

Here is the model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Final_Year_Project.Models
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(RegistrationMetaData)) ]
    public partial class Registration
    {

    }

    public class RegistrationMetaData
    {

        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide First name.", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string Firstname { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide Last name.", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string Lastname { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide User name.", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Remote("IsAvailable", "Home", ErrorMessage = "This User name is already exist")]
        public string Username { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide Password.", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        //[NotMapped]
        //[CompareAttribute("Password,",ErrorMessage="Confirm Password does not match")]
        //[DataType(DataType.Password)]
        //public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide Email.", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        //[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide Date of birth.", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        //[DataType(DataType.Date)]
        //[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "")]
        //public DateTime? DOB { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide Gender.", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string Gender { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: That happens because your model is not in a valid state. Can you post it?

Comment: i have posted the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a different ViewModel for your login form, as `RegistrationMetaData` has more required fields than you post in your login (like `FirstName` and `LastName`).

Create a new model for login nd use it:

```
public class LoginMetaData
{        
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Remote("IsAvailable", "Home", ErrorMessage = "This User name is already exist")]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please provide Password.", AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Then use it in your view:

```
@model LoginMetaData
```

And in controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(LoginMetaData U)
{
    Response.Write(U.Username); // it print the name but not go inside the condition
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {                        // not come here why?
        Response.Write("inin");
        ModelState.Clear();
        using (Database1Entities db = new Database1Entities())
        {
            var user = db.Registrations.Where(a => a.Username.Equals(U.Username) && a.Password.Equals(U.Password)).FirstOrDefault();
            if (user != null)
            {
                Session["LoggedUserID"] = U.Id.ToString();
                Session["LoggedUsername"] = U.Username.ToString();
                return RedirectToAction("Update");
            }
        }
    }
    return View();
}
```